# ¿Cómo agregar sombra a una gráfica lineal con chartjs y vuejs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

¿Cómo puedo agregar sombra a una gráfica lineal?
Estoy utilizando esas librerías:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs/dist/vue-chartjs.min.js"></script>
```

Ya logré generar la gráfica, únicamente necesito agregarle sombras.

Estoy utilizando vuejs utilizando cdn.
Lo genero de la siguiente manera:

```
    Vue.component("salesChart", {
      extends: VueChartJs.Line,
      props: {
        chartdata: {
          type: Object,
          default: null,
        },
        options: {
          type: Object,
          default: null,
     
      },
      mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options);

        });
      },
```